# Angular get files.length from firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I've problem, it means I'd like to get the length of items located on the firebase storage.

```
for(let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
      const storage = firebase.storage().ref().child('21/' + i + '.png');
      storage.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        this.small_img_src.push(url);
      });
    }
```

something like that, it work's ofc when I have a 3 images over there. But I'd like to finish this loop when It will be lower than images.length... I don't know how to get an information about all images located over there ;/

tools: Angular 6 and Angularfire2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what files are present in a Cloud Storage bucket, you can use the [`list` or `listAll` APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files) of the Firebase client-side SDK.

Sample code based on the linked documentation:

```
// Create a reference under which you want to list
var storage = firebase.storage();

var storageRef = storage.ref();

// Find all the prefixes and items.
storageRef.listAll().then(function(result) {
  result.items.forEach(function(itemRef) {
    // All the items under listRef.
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});
```